# How to start reading a file(CSV) from a given line n in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a large CSV file. I want to start reading from line n. Currently I have the following code

```
CSV.foreach(path) do |row|
  #process
end
```

I need to start reading from file n.

Comment: Are the lines before `n` CSV data or just a bunch of text?

Comment: CSV they are CSV records

Comment: have the lines (or columns) always the same length or may it differ? And remember, with UTF-8 the bytes may differ, even if there a similar numbers of characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can read specific rows using [.readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-readlines) method:

```ruby
require 'csv'

p CSV.readlines(path)[15..20] # array returned

# Benchmark 
#     user     system      total        real
# 0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.015769)
```

Other way(which, I believe, should not load entire file in memory):

```
from = 15
to = 20
csv = CSV.open(file, 'r')

# skipping rows before one we need
from.times { csv.readline }

# reading rows we need
(to - from).times { p csv.readline }

# Benchmark 
#     user     system      total        real
# 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000737)
```

Comment: It is large file >10gb wouldnt readlines hog the entire memory?

Comment: @yatishmehta do you know specific lines which you want to read? I mean from `i` to `j`?